# Launching Inteliji IDEA gives an error. How can I fix that?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I think it has something to do with the idea.exe.vmoptions.

[image: Error]

Here is what is inside the vmoptions file

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Do I need to remove or add something to this file?

Comment: The error message in a window says what you need to do...

Comment: What execution file do you run - idea.exe or idea64.exe? Do you use 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

For some reason IntelliJ is not able to install its own version of java in your computer. It tries to do it in E:\Programs\IntelliJ...
Check for right permissions or harddisk space.

The messege tells you that IntelliJ installation of its own java is not mandatory, because if you have your own version you can make IntelliJ run on it. To choose this second option do what message says.

Comment: I already created a JAVA_HOME path to JDK in the environment variables but the same error still appears. I still think it has something to do with vmoptions since I changed it recently to make java fx work

Comment: I would rather investigate why IntelliJ cannot create its own jvm directory. Anyway open a cmd console and launch ./bin/idea; checking the output can help

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to vmoptions file. See [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) for the sequence of variables IDE checks when searchig for JDK to run under. You can define the `IDEA_JDK_64` with the path pointing to the 64bit JDK installation. By default the IDE uses the bundled JDK so you can set the bundled JDK path for it. Just make sure the installation home has the `jre64` directory which should be present by default unless you've explicitly downloaded distribution without bundled jre.